# AWS Route 53 DNS multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am looking into using multiple AWS accounts for my organization, the accounts are as follows:

- billing (centralized for all accounts)
- security (central account for AWS IAM roles/credentials)
- app1-prod (prod environment)
- app1-non-prod (staging/test environment)

and then any additional apps (the idea is that these can scale out)

- app2-prod (prod environment)
- app2-non-prod (staging/test environment)

I am trying to follow the suggestion from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqq39mZKQXU) AWS re:Invent talk.

My question is as follows, how do I configure Route 53 to route traffic for prod requests (`www.prod.app1.my-company.com`) to the app1-prod account and its load balancers and traffic for the staging/test environment (`www.test.app1.my-company.com`)?

Or should each account owns its own DNS record in Route53?
For example instead of `www.prod.app1.my-company.com` and `www.test.app1.my-company.com` use: `www.app1.com` and `www.app1-test-account-my-company.com`

I am aware of [route53 resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/) but that seems geared towards hybrid clouds (on-prem and cloud VPC's).

Thanks in advance.

Note: The URLs above are not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that occurs to me right now is to use a different URL structure. If you have to use the URL structure you've given above please edit the question to indicate that's mandatory.

For example, you could use

```
prod-app.example.com
```

and

```
test-app.example.com
```

Rather than

```
prod.app1.my-company.com
```

and

```
test.app1.my-company.com
```

**Using specified URL structure**

If you need the URL structure above, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/817651/can-different-aws-accounts-manage-different-subdomains/817807) could potentially help

Comment: Thank you Tim! Finally got around to implementing this, the accepted answer in the mentioned question works 100%