# different AWS accounts manage different subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, subdomain, dns-zone, amazon-route53

I've checked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/817651/can-different-aws-accounts-manage-different-subdomains) answer but it didn't help.

I'm moving `example.biz` to R53 zone in one AWS account ("parent") and want to manage subdomain `api.example.biz` in another ("child") account.

I've created `api.example.biz` in the child acc:
[image]

Then I took those 4 NSes and added them to `example.biz` in the parent acc:
[image]

When I try to resolve `test.api.example.biz` the resolving process stops at those NSes:

```
dig @ns-1210.awsdns-23.org api.example.biz #here is the NS of the `example.biz`

.....
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.example.biz.            IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
api.example.biz.     600     IN      NS      ns-1394.awsdns-46.org.
api.example.biz.     600     IN      NS      ns-1539.awsdns-00.co.uk.
api.example.biz.     600     IN      NS      ns-691.awsdns-22.net.
api.example.biz.     600     IN      NS      ns-9.awsdns-01.com.
```

That's the end, no more resolving. The only idea I have is the domain is not switched to AWS yet, it is at the previous, non-R53 NS right now. Thus, when I run `dig @ns-1210.awsdns-23.org api.example.biz` instead of `dig api.example.biz` it does not go recursively. I tried to spoof this and edit `/etc/resolv.conf` leaving the only line

```
nameserver 205.251.196.186 (this is where ns-1210.awsdns-23.org points at)
```

but it didn't help either, `dig api.example.biz` returns the same answer. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm curious why would you want to do this? And do you really need different Route53 hosted zones, or can you have one account control the hosted zone and have the DNS entries point to the alias / A / cname record for the resources in other accounts?

Comment: To reduce blast radius: different people are responsible for different subdomains. Infrastructure is in the different accounts also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my guess was correct: everything becomes OK after the DNS switch. Nevertheless, it'd be useful to know how to test such settings before the switch.